# Angular JS POST request not sending JSON data

Tags: web-services, http, angularjs, flask

I am trying to send an object as JSON to my webservice in Flask that is expecting JSON in the request data.

I have tested the service manually by sending JSON data and it works fine. However, when I try to make a http POST request through angular controller, the web server sends me a message saying it did not receive JSON.

When I inspect the request headers in Chrome it appears that data is not being sent in JSON but regular key/value pairs even through the Content Type is set to application/json

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:49
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Referer:http://localhost:5000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
application=AirFare&d1=10-APR-2013&d2=14-APR-2013
```

If you seen the last line below Request Payload, you can see the data is not in JSON format.

This is the HTTP POST call in my angular controller:

```
$http({
            url: '/user_to_itsr',
            method: "POST",
            data: {application:app, from:d1, to:d2},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.users = data.users; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
            });
};
```

I am sending the data as an object {} but I have tried to send it after serializing by JSON.stringify however, nothing I do seems to send JSON to the server.

Really appreciate if somebody can help out.

Comment: $http POST sends its data by default as JSON encoded. Try removing ```headers``` from your $http call. It's possible that you are overwriting the default headers and that this leads to unexpected results on the server. You can also post your request headers to double-check.

Comment: @smartexpert did u find the solution? i have the same problem, i try alot to find a solution for it but i can't, if u find the solution plz help me. thanks alot

Answer (score 49):

If you are serializing your data object, it will not be a proper json object.  Take what you have, and just wrap the data object in a `JSON.stringify()`.

```
$http({
    url: '/user_to_itsr',
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({application:app, from:d1, to:d2}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.users = data.users; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
});
```

Comment: My problem was I had `data: {someVar: JSON.stringify(myVar)}`, not what's in this answer.

Answer (score 10):

I have tried your example and it works just fine:

```js
var app = 'AirFare';
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();

$http({
    url: '/api/test',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: {application: app, from: d1, to: d2}
});
```

Output:

```
Content-Length:91
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:1234
Origin:http://localhost:1234
Referer:http://localhost:1234/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
{"application":"AirFare","from":"2013-10-10T11:47:50.681Z","to":"2013-10-10T11:47:50.681Z"}
```

Are you using the latest version of AngularJS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FormData API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

```
var data = new FormData;
data.append('from', from);
data.append('to', to);

$http({
    url: '/path',
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    transformRequest: false,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
})
```

This solution from http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

you can use your method by this way

```
var app = 'AirFare';
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();

$http({
    url: '/api/apiControllerName/methodName',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {application:app, from:d1, to:d2},
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
    //timeout: 1,
    //cache: false,
    //transformRequest: false,
    //transformResponse: false
}).then(function (results) {
    return results;
}).catch(function (e) {

});
```

Comment: should be `data:` not `params:`

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. All others do not work if you need to have  several @RequestParams

Answer (score 0):

try to use absolute url. if it not works, check if service's response has headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers

for example:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following to find the posted data.

`data = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)`

Answer (score -1):

```
$http({
    url: '/api/user',
    method: "POST",
    data: angular.toJson(yourData)
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.users = data.users;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
});
```