# AngularJS - $http.post send data as json

Tags: json, angularjs, http, post

I'm working on autocomplete directive with angularjs but having some issues.

I have a form which have an autocomplete input. When i type something there, the **term variable** is sent as JSON:

[image]

But, when i use the same function (from different angular controller, but the same function) in another form the **term variable** sent perfectly and the autocomplete works fine:

[image]

Here is my angular function:

```
$scope.getCustomers = function (searchString) {
    return $http.post("/customer/data/autocomplete",
        {term: searchString})
        .then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
};
```

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Only relevant thing I noticed in the docs was "If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format." but if in the both places where you call getCustomers you are passing just a string, then I don't know why it would act differently.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. Can you try the suggested answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547227/angular-js-post-request-not-sending-json-data

Comment: You need to provide the HTML for the forms and the JavaScript that is actually calling this method. Otherwise, anything anyone says will just be a guess. I'm willing to bet you have a bug elsewhere.

Answer (score 47):

Use JSON.stringify() to wrap your json

```
var parameter = JSON.stringify({type:"user", username:user_email, password:user_password});
    $http.post(url, parameter).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log(data);
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```

Comment: If I am referencing this parameter in server code, does it just get sent in the body of the request or is there some way to give the parameter a key so I can pick it up by a reference key in my server?

Answer (score 18):

Consider explicitly setting the header in the $http.post (I put application/json, as I am not sure which of the two versions in your example is the working one, but you can use application/x-www-form-urlencoded if it's the other one):

```
$http.post("/customer/data/autocomplete", {term: searchString}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
```

Answer (score 12):

i think the most proper way is to use the same piece of code angular use when doing a "get" request using you `$httpParamSerializer` will have to inject it to your controller so you can simply do the following without having to use Jquery at all ,     `$http.post(url,$httpParamSerializer({param:val}))`

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializer){
  $http.post(url,$httpParamSerializer({param:val,secondParam:secondVal}));
}
```