# bad request with angularjs $http.post and spring restful

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a method in server(with spring restful):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lastQuestions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<QuestionEntity> getLastQuestions(@RequestParam("count") Integer count) throws SQLException {

    List<QuestionEntity> _result = _Impl.getLast(count);
    return _result;

}
```

in angularjs :

```
   var _url = 'http://localhost:8080/Tabaraee/service/question/lastQuestions';

        $http.post(_url,{count:10}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        });
```

but get error :

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8080/Tabaraee/service/question/lastQuestions"
```

response :

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'count' is not present</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Required Integer parameter 'count' is not present</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.57</h3></body></html>
```

why ?

Comment: As the error message said `Required Integer parameter 'count' is not present`

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring, but you are sending count as a request body, but trying to receive it as a parameter. Request body and request parameter are different things.

Comment: Rebornix , use of $http.post(_url,{count:10}) for send parameter 'count'

Comment: @O.R try sending request to `http://localhost:8080/Tabaraee/service/question/lastQuestions?count=10`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545072/angularjs-http-post-send-data-as-json

Comment: @Rebornix , I want to send request post , Not request Get

Comment: Do `$http.post(_url,JSON.stringify({count:10}))`

Answer (score 2):

Provide your *count* value map as a string, from the angular docs

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. If the value
>   is not a string, it will be JSONified.

so you have two options, either stringify the parameters

```
    $http.post(_url,JSON.stringify({count:10})).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    });
```

or, you can leave your client side code as is, in which case the parameters will be send as JSON inside a request body, and therefore you would have to change your server side to bind from the request body, by changing the *@RequestParam* to *@RequestBody*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lastQuestions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<QuestionEntity> getLastQuestions(@RequestBody("count") Integer count) throws SQLException {
```

Comment: use of $http.post(_url,{count:10}) for send parameter 'count'