# angular.js http.POST contains no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm starting out learning the MEAN stack, so apologies of this is a stupid question. I'm adapting a few tutorials to my own project, and I've made a simple REST api to a database of books.

```
// add book and return updated list
app.post('/api/books', function(req, res) {
    console.log("New book: ", JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));
    Book.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        pageCount: 100,
    }, function(err, book) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return updated list
        Book.find(function(err, books) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(books);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use angular to interface with this, like so:

```
$scope.createBook = function() {
    console.log('Trying to create ', $scope.formData);
    $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/api/books', data: $scope.formData}).then(function (response) {
        $scope.formData = {};   // reset form
        console.log('CREATE Success: ', response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('CREATE Error: ', error);
    });
};
```

The output I get from the `createBook`-function is `Trying to create  – {title: "amazingTitle", author: "amazingAuthor"}`, which is as it should be, but the output from the API handler is `New book:  {}`, which is of course not what I want. I realise this might not be enough detail to go on, but where could I be going wrong here?

Comment: It might help you to do `console.log("New book: " + JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));` to see exactly what the object contains

Comment: Also, and this is a small detail, the `.success()` and `.error()` are deprecated. It is preferred to use the returned promise with `.then(successCB, failureCB)`

Comment: @pulseOne Thanks, I tried that, and I got New book: {}

Comment: check in browser debug tools whether they are getting posted to server & also make sure you are using body parser module on the server side

Comment: In your node server, are you using a body parser?

Comment: We have no idea where `$scope.formData` comes from. verify what it actually is also before sending

Comment: I am using body-parser, yes

Comment: @charlieftl, I used console.log to check the formData, it does contain the correct json

Comment: Also `console.log("New book: " + req.body);` is concatenating string to object which is lways cast to string as ` [object Object]`  use `,` instead of `+` or separate logs

Comment: @charlieftl Thanks! I didn't know

Comment: I updated the question as I implemented some of your suggestions.

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see exactly what gets sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an error with the body-parser setup, I'd only set the app to use urlencoded, not json.

Answer (score -2):

JSON.stringify() your data.

c.f. [AngularJS - $http.post send data as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545072/angularjs-http-post-send-data-as-json)

my POST calls typically take this form:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: url, headers: headers, data: JSON.stringify(request)}).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        // do something
    }, function(error) {
        // do something
    });
```

Comment: No need to stringify...it is done by default internally in `$http` api

Comment: Nothing wrong with OP signature for `$http.post('/api/books', $scope.formData)`. i personally use that a lot