# Controller receives Null arguments from angularjs service post

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm having an issue posting data to my controller using angularjs.

The data looks good while debugging, right until it hits my controller and then the arguments being passed in are always null.

```
public class NewCompArgs {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }

        }

        //Tested with [HttpPost] here, and it didn't work
        // Tested using [FromBody]NewCompArgs args, and splitting 
        // out into Name and Decription strings with [FromBody]
        public ActionResult AddNewComponent(NewCompArgs args) 
        {
            Component NewComp = new Component
            {
                Name = args.Name,
                Description = args.Description
            };
            _context.Add(NewComp);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(NewComp);
        }
```

NewCompArgs args is null every time.

Here is the service I use to hit my controller:

```
app.factory('Components', function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

    service.AddNewComponent = function (args) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/Components/AddNewComponent', { args: args }).then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return service;
});
```

Here is the angular controller function:

```
$scope.newComponent = function () {
        Components.AddNewComponent($scope.compArgs).then(function (response) {
        });
    }
```

Just an example of the data I'm getting during debugging

Angular Controller:
[ng controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIDtt.jpg)

Angular Service:
[ng service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckrmc.jpg)

MVC Controller:
[MVC Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljCPF.jpg)

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're passing `{ args: args }` but the server is expecting an object which contains `name` and `description`, not `args`.

Comment: Did you try to hit this method using `PostMan` API client? is it working there properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - $http.post send data as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545072/angularjs-http-post-send-data-as-json)

Comment: @osm0sis You are returning `ActionResult` - it's wrong. I think you are extending `Controller` instead of `ApiController`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this can help, but in Angular 2/5 when u want to trigger an method in a controller you can use method().subscribe(); maybe this will help you.

Comment: He's using angularjs.

Comment: I know, that's the reason I'm not sure if it's help but he should try.