# How to pass Body to POST method in angular 2

Tags: angular, post, http-post, angular5, angular2-services

In my scenario,body of the POST method is like-

> {   "deleteList" :[ "5ab32csa2" , "5baweq34da" , "5cwqr5wer" ] }

I want to send this data  object to the POST method same as above.
I tried with many different postings with headers an body and Finally I got the below answer...====>>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - $http.post send data as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545072/angularjs-http-post-send-data-as-json)

Comment: Guys, this question is not really a duplicate, Angular 2 and Angularjs are different

Comment: You are right @CommercialSuicide

Comment: Some people still think that Angularjs and Angular 2 is same,but actually their is huge drastic change in structure of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I got the answer====>

```
 deletemyData(selectedIdList){
  return this.http.post(
      this.deletemyDataUrl,
      JSON.stringify ({ deleteList : selectedIdList }) ,
      { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')}
    ); 
  }
```

Comment: This answer is easy as compaire to the other with respect to "Angular 2/4/5"

Answer (score 2):

I use this exemple:

```
save(): Promise<any[]> {
const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': this.auth.token });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify ({ deleteList : selectedIdList }), options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
}
```