# Error when doing post with express JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, crud

I am testing the post method to create a todo item as follows. I am using postman in chrome to simulate the post method call. However, it does not work and gives me the below error. I suspect something is wrong with the way body-parser library is working. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
1  SyntaxError: Unexpected token b
2:    at parse (/Users/zack/mydrive/proj/express-demo/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
3:    at /Users/zack/mydrive/proj/express-demo/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
4:    at invokeCallback (/Users/zack/mydrive/proj/express-demo/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
5:    at done (/Users/zack/mydrive/proj/express-demo/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
6:    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/zack/mydrive/proj/express-demo/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
7     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
8     at _stream_readable.js:908:16
```

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//MIDDLEWARE
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// TODOS
var todos = [
  { body: "take out the trash",completed: false},
  { body: "Do the laundry",completed:true},
  { body: "Make a screencast",completed:false}
]

app.post('/todos', function (req, res){
  console.log("todo:", req.body);
  var todo = req.body;
  console.log("todo:"+todo);
  todos.push(todo);
  res.status(200).json(todo);
  res.send('OK')
})
```

Further I observe that the problem is because of this line.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Whats the data you're sending in postman look like?

Comment: Make sure your data is valid JSON. My guess is that you're using JavaScript syntax instead. For example, JavaScript syntax would be `{ bar: "baz" }` but JSON needs to have keys quoted for example: `{ "bar": "baz" }`.

Comment: @tymeJV Added screenshot of postman

Comment: @mscdex I dont need to worry about this when I am using postman

Comment: Do you have `Content-Type` overridden in the "Headers" tab/section?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are sending the request as JSON? Make sure you've selected it in Postman - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nSV7.jpg.

If that didn't work, you can try the following -

...

```
app.post('/todos', function (req, res){
  console.log("todo:", req.body);
  var todo = req.body;
  console.log("todo:"+todo);
  todos.push(todo);

  // Only try to send a single response.
  res.json(todo);
});
```

It looks like you were trying to send two responses, one containing JSON, and another with text/plain ('Ok').

http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.json

Comment: No. That is not the problem. I am using one res at a time. I comment out the other. I forgot to comment when pasting the code here. Your solution does not solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your program is trying to interpret the post data as json data - and generating an error when it trys to parse the request data which is probably url-encoded.

Perhaps consider sending your data in json format. You will have to set the request headers to indicate the datatype is json. See this answer for an example:

[Angular JS POST request not sending JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547227/angular-js-post-request-not-sending-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new session in postman and it started working. I am not sure if there is a caching effect but it works now. I did not make any code change at all. Posting this as the solution now.

Comment: I just copied all the code 1:1 and there wasn't any problems (ran as expected). I'm glad you managed to find a ray around it.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put quotes on your JSON value.

Not **"okay2"** but just **okay2**.

I think that postman adds the quotes himself if needed and in this case creates ""okay2"" which isn't valid JSON.

By the way you can test by clicking on the "row" radio button and write your own JSON.