# AngularJS $http.post succeeds but doesn't save the data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm trying to save an array into a JSON file that's located on a webserver.
The response is successful but when I open the JSON it's completely empty.

I've tried to create a JSON object of my own manually but it yielded same results.

Here's the process:

```js
app.controller('BookController', ['$window', '$http', function ($window, $http) {
this.contacts = [];

this.exportContacts = function(contacts){
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/data/contacts.json',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: contacts
    }).then(function goodCall(){
        $window.alert("Save done!");
    }, function badCall(){
        $window.alert("Failed to save error! error: " + $http.status);
    });
};
}]);
```

I fill the array with inputs via form:

```html
<form name="addCont" ng-show="showForm" ng-controller="ContactController as contactCtrl" ng-submit="contactCtrl.addContact(addCont, bookCtrl.contacts)" novalidate>
<label>
    First Name:
    <input name="fname" type="text" required ng-pattern="/^(\D)+$/" ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.firstName"></input>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="addCont.fname.$dirty && addCont.fname.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="addCont.fname.$error.required">First Name is required.</span>
        <span ng-show="addCont.fname.$error.pattern">First name must contain letters only!</span>
    </span>
</label>
<label>
    Last Name:
    <input name="lname" type="text" ng-pattern="/^(\D)+$/" ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.lastName"></input>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="addCont.lname.$dirty && addCont.lname.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="addCont.lname.$error.pattern">Last name must contain letters only!</span>
    </span>
</label>
<label>
    Phone Number:
    <input name="phone" type="tel" required ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.phone" ng-minlength="9" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/"></input>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="addCont.phone.$dirty && addCont.phone.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="addCont.phone.$error.minlength">Phone number is too short!</span>
        <span ng-show="addCont.phone.$error.maxlength">Phone number is too long!</span>
        <span ng-show="addCont.phone.$error.required">Phone number is required!</span>
        <span ng-show="addCont.phone.$error.pattern">Must not contain letters!</span>
    </span>
</label>
<label>
    Notes:
    <input name="notes" type="text" ng-model="contactCtrl.contact.notes"></input>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="addCont.fname.$invalid || addCont.lname.$invalid || addCont.phone.$invalid" />
</form>
```

So the array should look somethings like this:

```
[{
    firstName: "Tim",
    lastName: "asdxc",
    notes: "asdasd",
    phone: "0532753940"
},{
    firstName: "Timz",
    lastName: "asdasd",
    notes: "asdasd",
    phone: "123123123"
}]
```

Do I somehow need to parse the array before sending it?

Comment: i think the url you give to $http is a web service. It will not work with a file

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547227/angular-js-post-request-not-sending-json-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, you are missing an important peace. You need some RESTful like service on your server. Otherwise your not able to save/write to files on your server.

I recommend you to get familiar with [node](https://nodejs.org) and may be [express](http://expressjs.com/) for the start.

Answer (score 0):

The url you give to $http should be a web service. 
It will not work with a file.

You have to create a webservice who create the file on server side ( php / node.js / java ... ) and call it from $http

Answer (score 0):

I think url property must be 'api/contacts':
Given that you must have a web service or web api controller: ContactsController

`$http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'api/contacts',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: contacts
    }).then(function goodCall(){
        $window.alert("Save done!");
    }, function badCall(){
        $window.alert("Failed to save error! error: " + $http.status);
    });`